# Can't run PHP file in console

Tags: php

Using command:

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/my/file.php");
echo $output;
```

Getting this result:

```
    string(1208) "Content-type: text/html string(1165) "Content-type: text/html string(1122) "Content-type: text/html string(1079) "Content-type: text/html string(1036) "Content-type: text/html string(994) "Content-type: text/html string(952) "Content-type: text/html string(910) "Content-type: text/html string(868) "Content-type: text/html string(826) "Content-type: text/html string(784) "Content-type: text/html string(742) "Content-type: text/html string(700) "Content-type: text/html string(658) "Content-type: text/html string(616) "Content-type: text/html string(574) "Content-type: text/html string(532) "Content-type: text/html string(490) "Content-type: text/html string(448) "Content-type: text/html string(406) "Content-type: text/html string(364) "Content-type: text/html string(322) "Content-type: text/html string(280) "Content-type: text/html
Warning: shell_exec() [function.shell-exec]: Unable to execute '/usr/bin/php /home/zumblemo/public_html/ad/../test.php' in /home/zumblemo/public_html/ad/test.php on line 5
bool(false) " " " " " " " " " " " " " "
```

It should just output the word "Test" for now.
I don't get it.
When I launch Python files like this it works. 
Hosting support says that same should work with PHP files.

Paths are 100% correct (when they are incorrect - it just gives NULL result like it should)

PS:
Great!
php-cli worked.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code for `/home/zumblemo/public_html/ad/test.php on line 5`? ***snip*** (moved to an answer)

Comment: why not just include file.php or file_get_contents it

Comment: @JohnSmith I just moved that part of my comment to an answer. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your script is recursively calling itself until a recursion limit is reached. It also looks like php might be a symlink to php-cgi. Try calling php-cli instead.